# Flutter Geolocator Location doesn't obtain for real phones

Tags: flutter, geolocation

I used geolocator flutter package for my little app and it works perfectly with emulator, but when I try to use in my real smart phone, it doesnt work. Do you have any idea?

```
void getLocationData() async {
    WeatherModel weatherModel = WeatherModel();
    var weatherData = await weatherModel.getLocationWeather();
    //print(weatherData);
    var zipCode = await weatherModel.getLocationZipCode();
    zipCode = zipCode.toString().substring(0, 2);

    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
      return LocationScreen(
        locationWeather: weatherData,
        zipCode: zipCode,
      );
    }));
  }
```

```
Future<dynamic> getLocationWeather() async {
    Location location = Location();
    await location.getCurrentLocation();

    NetworkHelper networkHelper = NetworkHelper(
        '$openWeatherMapURL?lat=${location.latitude}&lon=${location.longitude}&appid=$apiKey&units=metric');

    var weatherData = await networkHelper.getData();
    return weatherData;
  }
```

Comment: which geolocator plugin you use ?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator

Answer (score 2):

Angela Yu's student? her projects need one update for optimizing and fixing little errors.

I got problems with Geolocator, it was not being used correctly, and [this site](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/flutter-geolocator-plugin) helped me a lot. Then I made my own Location class with Provider and... life becomes good again.

Answer (score 0):

Try use [geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator). I seems you are not using geolocator package

```
final Geolocator geolocator = Geolocator()..forceAndroidLocationManager;
// return true if location service is enable, false if not
bool locationServiceEnable = await geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
// position instace
Position position;

// if location service enable get current position
if (locationServiceEnable) {
  // await current position
  position = await geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
      desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best);
  // if location service is not enable get last known position
} else {
  // await last known position
  position = await geolocator.getLastKnownPosition(
      desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best);
}

if (position != null) {
  // fetch weather data with position data
}
```

Comment: I used geolocator, but I didnt insert it in the code above.

Comment: This is the way you are using geolocator? look at my edited answer

Comment: The Location constructor inside your code is taken from the geolocator plugin?

Comment: Did you add this permissions to android menifest file ?

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />  

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

Comment: Yeap, I did too

Comment: There is something wierd, when I use geolocator plugin I dont have the location constructor

Comment: It says `Geolocator()..forceAndroidLocationManager`, it should say `Geolocator()..forceAndroidLocationManager=true`. Check: https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator

Answer (score 0):

You should add

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

to the AndroidManifest.xml. It helps to use the internet to fetch location data in an Android device, because your app still need to get data from URL openweathermap.

Answer (score 0):

using geolocator: ^7.0.1
and adding

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

to AndroidManifest.xml file

```
void getLocation() async {
    print('getLocation');
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    print(position);
}
```

and using in onPressed

```
onPressed: () {
        getLocation();
      },
```

solves the problem.